# Which one of the following sentences are correct?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Is the following sentence correct?

> *I always **fear making** someone feel sad when I talk.*

or I should say:

> *I always **fear to make** someone feel sad when I talk.*

Doesn't the last one mean that I want to make someone feel sad, but I fear I can't do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. The second is just broken. It doesn't even have your alternate "I want to make someone feel sad..." meaning.

** Addition **

I was trying to figure out why the second is broken. After all, something like this is OK (if a bit stilted):

> I always cry to make someone feel sad when I talk

or

> I always whine to make someone feel sad when I talk

or

> I always love to make someone feel sad when I talk

or even

> I always fart to make someone feel disgusted when I talk

So I'm not sure what it is about the verb *"to fear"* that makes it unsuitable in this context (but idiomatically at least it *is* unsuitable). I'd suggest it's because "to fear" is a transitive verb, but so is "to love". Shrug.